# rails error making field unique

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I get this when trying to run the migration:

> Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'repeat' for key 'index_industries_on_name':
>
> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_industries_on_name` ON `industries` (`name`)
> ```

Migration is `add_index :industries, :name, {:unique => true}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two or more rows with `"repeat"` as the industry name. You cannot make the `name` column of your `industries` table unique until you fix this.

Comment: Yes, I found that I had to resolve the duplicate name data before being able to add the index. Thank You.